# Facebook Login button failed to re-size in 45 seconds

Tags: facebook, button, authentication, resize

I am attempting to implement an asynchronous loading Facebook log in button, but the button disappears after 45 seconds (in Google Chrome only) and this error message is logged in the error console: "FB:login_button failed to re-size in 45s".  How do I solve this problem?

Here are the errors that are logged in the error console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined connect.facebook.net.js:123
    v connect.facebook.net.js:123
    o.extend.constructor.ha connect.facebook.net.js:123
    g.inform connect.facebook.net.js:40
    (anonymous function) connect.facebook.net.js:123
    ka connect.facebook.net.js:67
    h.setWrapper.j connect.facebook.net.js:62
    r.register.init.s connect.facebook.net.js:66
    h.setWrapper.j connect.facebook.net.js:62
fb:login_button failed to resize in 45s
```

Here is the HTML:

```
         <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" size="xlarge" data-width="300" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
ADS.addEvent(window, "load", function(){


if(!ADS.$('fb_root')){

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "fb-root";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "dom/connect.facebook.net.js";
    var script2 = document.createElement("script");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
    head.appendChild(script);


    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

        FB.init({
        appId: "HIDDEN",
        channelUrl: "http://mywebsite.com/channel.php",
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
        });


    // Gets status when the user first lands
    // on site
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {

        //window.location="http://mywebsite.com";

      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

          // Do nothing, let the user view the welcome page
          //FB.login();

      } else {
          // this causes a login dialog to
          // pop up automagically once the user
          // lands on the site and is not logged in
          // or authorized
          //FB.login();

      }
     });

     function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // connected
                // using event subscribe to send user to right page, instead of this
                // which does not redirect the user once the login is complete
                //window.location="http://mywebsite.com/home.php?show=follow";
            } else {
                // cancelled
                //alert(response.authResponse);
            }
        });
    }
    FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function () { 
            // Redirect's the user once the login is complete
            window.location="http://mywebsite.com";
        })

    }   


}
});
```