# Facebook Send Button Appears Then Disappears on Firefox & IE but not on Chrome

Tags: plugins, cross-browser, send, xfbml

embedded a FB Send button using xfbml in an empty page. 
Page hosted on RackSpace and has nothing else on it.
The button appears and works normally, but after ~10 seconds disappears - only on FF and IE, not on Chrome.
Facebook's xfbml code injects a span containing an iFrame that contains the button.
When looking at the style of the span it seems that in Chrome width=50px height=20px but in Firefox height=width=0. Changing that manually causes the button to reappear.

Would really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: “Pics (= online example) or it didn’t happen.”

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the comment. It appears to be a bug in FB. I resolved it using:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210339/facebook-login-button-failed-to-re-size-in-45-seconds